# Convert a large number to words then round it

Tags: python, string, numbers

Lets say I have a large number. `154,342,231`
How can I use python to convert it to: "`154 million`"
and if I had a number like this: `6,213,341,987` convert it to "`6.2 billion`?"

Comment: Probably create a `dict` with a key `K` and value `1000` or `M`: `1000000` and then manipulate your string accordingly?

Comment: use the [num2words](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/) library with some trivial number rounding.

Comment: These are both a bit to tedious for my purposes. Sorry.

Comment: @NoahGerard num2word is tedious?

Comment: @DirtyBit I would have to change one-hundred-and-fifty-four-million-three-hundred-thousand-fourty-one-thousand .etc Lol to  154 million

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`num2words`](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/):

```
import num2words as n2w

s = '154,342,231'
s = s.replace(",", "")
print(n2w.num2words(s))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
one hundred and fifty-four million, three hundred and forty-two thousand, two hundred and thirty-one point zero
```

**OR**

Using [`humanize`](https://github.com/jmoiron/humanize):

```
import humanize
print(humanize.intword(s))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
154.3 million
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python library called [Humanize](https://github.com/jmoiron/humanize) which does exactly that. Try this :

```
import humanize
a = '154,342,231'
a = int(a.replace(',',''))
humanize.intword(a)    # '154.3 million'
```